# When performing mouse action for second time, I get MoveTargetOutOfBounds Exeption

Tags: selenium, webdriver

Im using ActionChains from selenium webdriver to click on particular spot on the canvas.
First time it works, but second, it throw an exception:

```
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_by_offset(650,500).click().perform()
time.sleep(2)
actions.move_by_offset(700,500).click().perform()
```

even if I change the values in second move_by_offset to (0,0) it gives an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/*****1.py", line 55, in <module>
actions.move_by_offset(700,500).click().perform()
File "/home/kuba/*****/action_chains.py", line 80, in perform
self.w3c_actions.perform()
File "/home/kuba/******/common/actions/action_builder.py", line 76, in perform
self.driver.execute(Command.W3C_ACTIONS, enc)
File "/home/*****python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/home/*******/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: Message: move target out of bounds
(Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.89)
```

**PLEASE NOTE**: the place I'm clicking on is a **canvas** - I can't even get a menu on it when rightmouse button is pressed.
Does the issue have something to do that this canvas gets focus from webdriver?

Comment: have you tried `actions.move_to_element_with_offset(element, x,y)`  - provide an element as a anchor so you start from a known point. You might find your first click isn't quite as expected.  It's difficult to guess what's going on when we don't know they application you're testing or screen resolution or what you're trying to do with the code in the first place.  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 issues here:
you need to reser actions with

```
actions.reset_actions()
```

the mouse moves from the last point, so giving values of (700,500) moved it outside of the screen = exception
Here is the working code:

```
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_by_offset(650,500).click().perform()
actions.reset_actions()
actions.move_by_offset(80,0).click().perform()
```

Comment: ActionChains is supposed to chain several actions to be run in a batch, no? That way there is a call to webdriver for each action.